# How do I view unprocessed orders in OpenCart 2.3 administration

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

The Sales > Order in OpenCart (ver 2.3) admin shows orders with statuses, e.g. Completed, Failed. I also need to view orders that were checked out but were not processed at all. These are orders with order_status_id equal to 0?

Is there a settings anywhere where I can opt to view unprocessed orders?

Comment: the order status is set by your payment extension.  whatever status you have set there is what it will be once the customer checks out.  it's up to you to change it to something else so you know that the order was processed.

Comment: also, you should note that the answer you accepted below does **not** do what you asked - it will show missing orders, i.e., orders that were not completed.  and it's pointless to have a vqmod for this since it's already built in to opencart - just select "Missing Orders" from the status filter to see these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a free vQmod script that displays unfinished orders:
[Unsuccessful orders](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=27060)

```
<modification>

    <id>Unsuccessfull Orders</id>

    <version>1.0</version>

    <vqmver>2.x</vqmver>

    <author>darbaze.com</author>



    <file name="admin/model/sale/order.php">

        <operation>

            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id > '0'";]]></search>

            <add><![CDATA[$sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id >= '0'";]]></add>

        </operation>

    </file>



    <file name="admin/view/template/dashboard/recent.tpl">

        <operation>

            <search position="replace" offset="1"><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>]]></search>

            <add><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>

            <tr class="<?php if($order['status']){ echo 'successfull'; } else { echo 'unsuccessfull'; } ?>">]]></add>

        </operation>

        <operation>

            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<td><?php echo $order['status']; ?></td>]]></search>

            <add><![CDATA[<td><?php if($order['status']){ echo $order['status']; } else { echo '---'; } ?></td>]]></add>

        </operation>

    </file>

    <file name="admin/view/template/sale/order_list.tpl">

        <operation>

            <search position="replace" offset="1"><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>]]></search>

            <add><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>

            <tr class="<?php if($order['status']){ echo 'successfull'; } else { echo 'unsuccessfull'; } ?>">]]></add>

        </operation>

        <operation>

            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<td class="text-left"><?php echo $order['status']; ?></td>]]></search>

            <add><![CDATA[<td class="text-left"><?php if($order['status']){ echo $order['status']; } else { echo '---'; } ?></td>]]></add>

        </operation>

    </file>



    <file name="admin/view/template/common/header.tpl">

        <operation>

            <search position="before"><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>]]></search>

            <add><![CDATA[<style>.successfull td{color:green;font-weight:bold} .unsuccessfull td{color:red}</style>]]></add>

        </operation>

    </file>



</modification>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll give this a try

Comment: this is not what the op asked for.  orders with status of 0 were not checked out.